# How to use SKPhysicsSlidingJoint?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I want to use SKPhysicsSlidingJoint to keep a ball on the bar while the bar moves left and right and the ball moves down. Essentially I want to keep the ball's X position the same as the bar's X position constantly. How can I use SKPhysicsSliding Joint to keep the ball and the bar together at all times?

What I want^
[image: What I want]

What happens ^
[image: What happens]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the bar and the ball to your scene. Set their initial positions. Then add the sliding joint:

```
let joint = SKPhysicsJointSliding.jointWithBodyA(bar.physicsBody,
    bodyB: ball.physicsBody, anchor: ball.position, axis: CGVectorMake(0, 1))
scene.physicsWorld.addJoint(joint)
```

You probably also want to set the distance limits on the joint. Example:

```
joint.lowerDistanceLimit = 0
joint.upperDistanceLimit = barLength
joint.shouldEnableLimits = true
```